# How to convert Swift optional into Objective-C

Tags: swift, firebase

I have read up on Swift optionals, specifically `if let`, but cannot make sense of this code. The tutorial is a swift project, but I am trying to use it to update an old Obj-C project. I am not trying to create an if let optional in objective-c, but rather just figure out how to make an Obj-C version do what he is doing here with Swift. The underlying code doesn't return a value.

```
if let user = user  << Obj alternative
```

Following a tutorial and here is the code:

```
[[FIRAuth auth] signInWithEmail:userEmail
                   password:userPass
                 completion:^(FIRUser * _Nullable user, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                            if(error == nil) { // No ERROR so already so user already in Firebase
                                if let user = user{
                                    NSDictionary *userData = @{ @"provider": user.providerID};
                                    [[DataService instance] createFirebaseDBUserWithUid:user.uid
                                                                      userData:userData
                                                                      isDriver:NO];
                                }
                                DLog(@"Email user Auth successfully in Firebase");
```

Here is the createFirebaseDBUserWithUid:user code (possible returns a Firebase id value)

```
@objc func createFirebaseDBUser(uid: String, userData: Dictionary<String, Any>, isDriver: Bool) {
    if isDriver {
        REF_DRIVERS.child(uid).updateChildValues(userData)
    } else {
        REF_USERS.child(uid).updateChildValues(userData)
    }
}
```

Would an obj-c version just be:

```
if( user != nil ){
    NSDictionary *userData = @{ @"provider": user.providerID};
    [[DataService instance] createFirebaseDBUserWithUid:user.uid userData:userData isDriver:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick with Objective-C of course is its behaviour if you send any message to a`nil` reference.

At the time of its invention (1986) it was actually *progress* to have any method sent to a `nil` reference (which is 'faulty' in an if statement since it is `0` (the number) at the same time) simply returning `nil` (or `0` if you interpret it as a number) and again 'faulty'.

In this sense you are 'mostly' correct if you do

```
if (user != nil)
```

in Objective-C wherever you see

```
if let user = user {
    ...
}
```

in Swift. Technically speaking it is not *entirely* the same, since the let-expression will give you a non-nullable reference to the same content shadowing the optional object *for the following scope*. So you do not have to do any more unwrapping of the `user` object in the scope of the if. Note however, that the user will again be optional after the if statement. This is adequately covered by the nil check in the Objective-C counterpart.

There may be "unusual" edge cases you could miss if the author of the Objective-C code relied on the "strange" interpretation of method passing in Objective-C. Nowadays it is considered bad practice to rely on these, but there used to be a time when we had chains of method calls that relied on said behaviour. Swift was invented partly to get rid of those sometimes unintended effects in method chains.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C `Type` is equivalent to `Type!` in Swift. for example: Objective-C `NSDictionary` would be `NSDictionary!` in Swift

Thus, Objective-C types are optionals by default and reading a Swift Type in Objective-C won't be affected by being an optional or not.

back to your question, as the intention of the code is not clear for me, generally, the code you wrote will generate a dictionary that contains one pair of (key, value) with the `providerID` which is not related to being optional or not.

the issue that you would face is if the `User` object was created in Swift, and you want to read it in Objective-C, then you have set it up for that